# How do I display function arguments in ipython qtconsole?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm using IPython qtconsole under windows 7, and when I first write a method name and type the bracket,  a popup shows method parameters.

What is the way to display that popup explicitly, once it has disappeared? This is pretty common 'show method parameters' shortcut that I'm talking about, but I've failed to find the shortcut to it after an embarrassing amount of google searches.

Comment: This might not be the perfect answer but I recommend using Spyder as an interactive editor showing you even more information by default (e.g. the docstring of the method as well...).

Answer (score 0):

In Spyder, try View - Panes - Object inspector. Then type the full name of the function.

Answer (score -1):

I would highly recommend relying on the [Python Library Reference](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/index.html) rather than any in-IDE tools, at least for functions and classes that are in the standard library. For objects outside those libraries however... it looks like you can type object_name followed by a question mark, that is, object_name?, to get a list of informative details about the object. (Since everything is an object, this presumably includes functions.)

For your specific question, it *looks*, from the iPython docs, like the TAB key is what you're looking for, but somehow I doubt you haven't already tried that.